# JBoss 7 : fluff or a real good application server?

Tags: jboss7.x

I am asking this especially, because JBoss AS 7+ has completely changed 360 degrees, enforcing the application developer to think completely in terms of JBoss Modules. That prevents earlier classpath-hell issues etc and encourages clean modular thinking etc. Also it claims a quick startup time etc.

All that is fine BUT my major concerns are thus, please confirm if you feel the same :

1. JBoss insists to put the jboss-deployment-structure.xml file inside WEB-INF. This would make the WAR file not portable at all since now it contains app server specific configuration files inside it. I am worried about inter-operability.
2. I am still nervous about the enormous amount of XML configuration needed - Create a module directory structure for each dependency you would like to add, create a module.xml for that dependency, create a jboss-deployment-structure.xml entries for non-modules or Manifest entries for libs inside WEB-INF/lib. etc etc. 
   That would require enough developer time and effort being spent towards being an configuration expert or hire an expert or buy the support - a significant cost in the long run for any team and company.

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing about jboss-deployment-structure.xml that makes it non-portable. Other application servers will simply ignore the file if they don't use it.

You do not need to create a module if you want to use a dependency in your application. You would only do that if you want to use a common dependency among several deployments. For example a JDBC driver library.

There is no need to create a jboss-deployment-structure.xml or add manifest entries for libraries in WEB-INF/lib. The only time you would need a jboss-deployment-structure.xml is if you want to exclude server dependencies, like log4j, or add dependencies outside the scope of your deployment that are not automatically added. There are probably some other use cases, but those are the most common.

Comment: I agree 100% with what James mentioned. Also if you go to any other vendors, you are still stuck with vendor specific XML's from my past experience. If you have problems in the App server, you will have to make a customer call while them, with jboss you can just look at the source. This a very rare thing to happen but looking at the code when needed really helps.  Also look for the stackoverflow tags of Jboss , Weblogic and Websphere. You will see that the jboss forum is more active than the other forums.